# Is the change between kernel/user mode done by hardware or software?

Tags: operating-system, paging, kernel

I was just wondering whether the switch between the kernel mode and the user mode in an operating system is done by the hardware or the os itself.
I understand that when a user process wants to get into kernel mode it can make a system call and execute some kernel code. When the system call is made, the process goes into the kernel mode and now all memory becomes accessible, etc. In order for this to happen, I would assume that the interrupt handler needs to switch or alter the page table. Is this true? If not, how does the CPU know, that it is running in the kernel mode and does not need to page fault when accessing restricted (unaccessible to the user process) memory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The last answer is actually not true....
Changing to kernel mode doesn't go through 'Real mode'. Actually after finishing the boot process, the computer never goes back to real mode.

In normal x86 systems, changing to kernel mode involves calling 'sysenter' (after setting parameters in some registers), which causes jumping a predefined address (saved in the MISR register of the CPU), that was set when the computer booted, because it can be done only from kernel mode (it is a 'privileged' command).

So it basically involves executing a software command, that the hardware responds to, by the way it was set, when it was in kernel mode

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a broad question - each hardware platform is going to do things slightly differently, but I think the basic answer is that it's done w/ software that leverages hardware facilities for memory protection, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I also found this site which i think explains it quite well: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/01/understanding-user-and-kernel-mode.html
Seems like the CPU knows whether to page fault or not based on values stored in the CS register (this might be x86 specific).

Answer (score 2):

When a user process wants to do a system call, it executes a special CPU instruction, and the CPU switches from virtual mode (for user processes, has page tables specific to processes) to real mode (for the kernel) and jumps to the OS syscall handler. The kernel can then do what it likes.

CPU support for this is required. The CPU keeps track of which mode it is in, where the page tables are located, jumping the instruction pointer, etc. It is triggered by the user software doing the syscall, and is dependent on the kernel providing support for whatever it is trying to do. As with all computation, it's always both hardware and software. I cannot be done solely with software however, because then there would be no way to prevent a process making a syscall from abusing the privelages it gains, e.g. it could start reading /etc/shadow.

Modern x86 computers have a special instruction just for doing system calls. Earlier x86 processors, and some current RISC ones, have an instruction to trigger an interrupt. Older architecures had other ways of switching control.